# Location of Notification area icons size in RegEdit Windows10

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-registry, taskbar, icons

I wonder if anybody has encountered with notification area icons size in Windows 10? Because after a Windows update the time panel under right-corner of screen

Before: https://i.stack.imgur.com/92BLg.png

After update : https://i.stack.imgur.com/41cS0.png

somehow disappeared. So there are still solutions about on the internet like unchecking "Lock The Taskbar" and dragging the  panel up or to not use small taskbar buttons.

So I decided to not settle with this and I thought that if I change the size of the icons maybe this can be fixed,

I searched in :

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics

but I didn't get the correct registry location.

Can anybody provide where this is?

Answer (score 0):

There is no registry value that controls the size of Notification Area icons.

You can reset the Taskbar to its default position (Bottom) & height with the following **PowerShell** (copy & past to console):

```
rp HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\StuckRects3 Settings
gps explorer | spps
```

But it doesn't affect the current state of Large/Small Taskbar icons or what toolbars are displayed, but toolbar divider positions are cleared.

Comment: somehow have to be there an way.Windows programmer made it with spesific registry.Otherwise these can't be fixed size as like there.But how.

Comment: No, nothing "has" to be in the registry, many aspects of appearance are hard-coded in .dlls